# Xcode10 - xcworkspace file only runs older version of my app

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, xcode10, xcode10.1

I am sure it is to do with *CocoaPods*, where the pod saved is outdated. I have tried to fix without resolution.

I have tried:
- Cleaning
- Running **pod install**, **pod update** separately in the containing folder
- Closing and reopening XCode after changes

It says the pod has been updated in the CLI but with no change when I run my app to an iPhone.

The **newest** version of the app runs on android. I have been developing my app with the Ionic framework using Visual Studio Code.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seemed to baffle people, I found that it was just a simple solution.

If anyone else has this issue in the future, what fixed it for me was simply:

ionic cordova platform **remove** ios
ionic cordova platform **add** ios

That's all folks.